# Do I still need to use key prop when mapping an array in a React Server Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-server-components

I don't think so, but just in case, does anyone know the answer and have a source?

When we map an array to React elements it's a good practice to add a key prop to each element (React will even warn you when you don't).

That's because it helps React know which element to update/remove when the array changes.

But in the case of React Server Components, since it's only rendered once in the server, is it still necessary?

**UPDATE**

I'm starting to think it's actually necessary. After upgrading to the latest Next and React versions I started getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot access XXX.prototype on the server. You cannot dot into a client module from a server component. You can only pass the imported name through.

And XXX is the name of a component that I'm mapping to.

These error went away as soon as I added the key prop to them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that keys in the RSC tree have a practical use case. When we emit a server action from the client, we receive a new version of the RSC tree. This tree is used to re-render the page, but the actual DOM tree as well as the React client tree can be recycled. If we don’t specify component keys on the server, we won’t be able to reconcile the new tree accurately, so client state may be either shifted or lost. It’d be interesting to run an experiment to confirm that.